# Comparing lists of objects and update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I have a view, passing a LIST of `Originals` to this method.
Before the post happened, i changed some of the properties. 
I now receive the updated list as a parameter in my method and would like
to update the database with these new values.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewValue(Page model)
    {

        var ListOfOriginals = Session.Query<Original>().ToList(); //GETS the objects i want to update

    listOfOriginals = Model.Pages // Model.page is the new list containing the updated values
    RavenSession.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When i debug, i can see that listOfOriginals gets the new values.
The problem is that i dont know how to update the RavenDB whith these new values.
I tried adding this: `Session.Store(listOfOriginals)` before the `SaveChanges()` but that resulted in an error. Maybe there is a much better way of doing this?

Comment: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/partial-document-updates

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am a beginner and its a bit over my head im afraid. Surely there must be an easy way to simply save the new list to raven?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the values from each Model.Pages value to the match existing value that you got from the db.

Comment: Thank you!
Could I ask you to provide a code example if possible?
Im very new to working with Raven.

Comment: `foreach(var item in Model.Pages) { session.Store(item); }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve all of the items you want, before you can update them.

I see you are using `session.Query<Original>().ToList()`. This is like a `SELECT * FROM Table` and RavenDB may not pull back everything on large data sets. It limits to 1024 per retrieve as it is a dangerous operation.

Instead, you can pull back the items in bulk by asking for them by ID. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewValue(Page model)
{
   var ids = Model.Pages.Select(x=>x.Id);

   var listOfOriginals = RavenSession.Load<Original>(ids.ToArray());

   // Modify values as you need to, as the RavenSession is tracking changes for you.

   RavenSession.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

RavenDB will be fast at retrieving items directly by key. Also note you do not have to indicate they are being changed, as the `IDocumentSession` is already tracking changes.

The only reason you need to use `IDocumentSession.Store` is adding new items. So for example, to add a new `Page`, consider this code:

```
// Adds a new page to RavenDB
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPage(Page model)
{   
   // Queues a new record for storage, giving it an ID to work with.
   RavenSession.Store(model);    

   // Commits to the DB
   RavenSession.SaveChanges();

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If you've worked with NHibernate, it works almost in an identical manner.